# Create a logging module that stores who access our system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an intranet web application which manage our company assets. And a new requirement have been raised that we need to have a module which logs who have signin inside the system . the first approach that came to my mind is to create a table named Login_Detials, with the following detials:-

> UserName
>
> Domain
>
> LoginTime
>
> ID (as the primary key)

Then insde my login action method to do something such as, which insert new login info :-

```
[HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
MembershipProvider domainProvider;
domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
   if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
      {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
Repository.insertNewLogin(model.UserName);// here i will be adding the login username
```

The above should work, but is there something out of the box that can give me such info (who login to my system)? Instead of building my code and table from scratch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ELMAH (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). This solution will cover application wide logging and will provide an interface for viewing the logs. In addition, you can manually write log entries so in your case specifically when a user logs into the application...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write code or write a minimal amount of code, I would probably use either Google Analytics or IIS logging for that. ELMAH is more for logging exceptions, which is not really what you want to do here. Enabling ELMAH is always a good idea, though :)